# Bad URL Error whir using CLGeocoder

Tags: ios, xcode, clgeocoder

Im getting this error `PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0xd4c2aa0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xd5ba660 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}`when I use this code:

```
CLGeocoder *geo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                     CCAlertView *askZip = [[CCAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Enter Zip Code" message:nil];
                     [askZip setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
                     UITextField *tf = [askZip textFieldAtIndex:0];
                     [askZip addButtonWithTitle:@"Enter" block:^{
                         [aUser setObject:[tf text] forKey:@"zip"];
                         NSLog(@"Zip code entered was %@",[tf text]);
                         if([tf text] == nil){
                             NSLog(@"CCalertView text is not being read");
                         }
                         [geo geocodeAddressString:[tf text] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                             for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
                             {
                                 NSLog(@"place--%@", [aPlacemark locality]);
                                 NSLog(@"lat--%f\nlong--%f",aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude,aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
                             }
....

}
```

I know this question has been asked before but the answer was not sufficient and I want to fix this problem as soon as possible. There are no updates for Xcode so I don't think it's an Xcode problem and it doesn't seem to be working on both the simulator AND actual devices...any possible solution?

Comment: Hey Im also facing the same issue.Are u able to solve it.Plz share ur answer if so

Comment: I just made it so that if it fails then I use reverse geolocation instead